In a shell script, how do I wait for a volume to be available?
This gives an error that file_on_volume_foo.txt is not available:
open /path/foo.dmg
open /Volumes/foo/file_on_volume_foo.txt

The file ... does not exist.


The command you are looking for is wait4path and is part of macOS
The man page  says

The wait4path program simply checks to see if the given path exists, and if so, it exits. Otherwise, it sleeps until the mount table is updated and checks again. The program will loop indefinitely until the path shows up in the file system namespace.

So knowing that:
wait4path /Volumes/foo/file_on_volume_foo.txt
open /Volumes/foo/file_on_volume_foo.txt


You can use hdiutil instead of having Finder mount the image via open, this will wait for the image to mount:
hdiutil attach /path/to/dmg
open /Volumes/foo/file.txt


I think the exact command sequence depends upon where /Volumes/foo is located. If it's located somewhere on your Macintosh HD I guess one of the other answers may work best. If it's on a Network drive (NAS, Samba, etc), here's a shell script that you might find useful:
Using test ([ ]):
#!/bin/bash

TF="/Volumes/foo"

if [ ! -f "$TF/file_on_volume_foo.txt" ]; then
   echo "could not find file; trying again in 5 seconds..."
   sleep 5
   if [ ! -f "$TF/file_on_volume_foo.txt" ]; then
      echo "Requested file is not available"
   else
      echo "Found file - is AVAILABLE"
   fi
fi

The point of the sleep 5 and re-testing for the presence of the file is to give your system a bit more time - a second chance if you will - to re-connect/mount.
And you can certainly put an open statement in the script. That will (AFAIK) start up a Finder window when the file is found.
You could also use the stat command - if for example, you're not sure what the filesystem is. To use an example from my system, where a file resides on a Synology NAS:
% TF="/Volumes/rpi_share/savedurl/id_value.txt" 
% stat -f $TF 

  File: "/Volumes/rpi_share/savedurl/id_value.txt"
    ID: 360000140000001e Namelen: ?       Type: smbfs
Block size: 1024       Fundamental block size: 1024
Blocks: Total: 28107205512 Free: 25002647236 Available: 25002647236
Inodes: Total: 28107205510 Free: 25002647236


What difference do you see between mounting a DMG and mounting a network share, in regards of waiting for the mount/open to complete?

Isn't this what wait4path does but wait4path hides away the test/loop/sleep ?

@mmmmmm: I don't really know what wait4path does b/c I've never used it. One thing I really didn't like about it was that it apparently will go into an infinite loop waiting on the path to appear. I think that might not be a wise command to put in a script - do you?

@nohillside: I guess there are a lot of diffs between mounting a local DMG, and mounting a share on a network drive/NAS. Beyond that, I may not understand your question???

Technically, there for sure are differences between mounting a dmg and mounting a network volume. But the OP seems primarily be interested in being sure that the mount has completed before accessing a file on the volume. Don‘t see how this differs.

@nohillside: Maybe that is what the OP was interested in, but if so, that wasn't entirely clear to me. Are you saying that hdiutil does wait, but that open does not wait? OTOH, maybe there's very little difference... my answer was based on my experience - that's all.

open does not mount anything it just tries to run the default app on the path supplied.

open just fires off the default app (Finder or its mounting utility in this case) via an Apple Event, and returns (not sure whether open -W would help in this case). OTOH, both hdiutil (for DMGs) and mount (for actual drives or network shares) wait til the target has been successfully mounted (or exit with an error code if not).
